# How can you disable qualcomm atheros in ubuntu 13.10 plazma kde desktop?

Tags: 13.10, internet

Help me quick for my job!! I have two Internet connections!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to disable a networking interface, you can temporarily remove its driver. Find out from the terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Your device will show a driver such as ath9k or alx or ath5k or some such at the line including 'driver=.' Simply unload the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r <some_driver>
```

Of course, substitute the driver you actually found. If you want it to be permanent, blacklist the driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist <some_driver>"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: Your answer heleped me a lot. I would vote for you but I don't have enough reputations... I had black listed my atheros on work and on my computer. Everything works perfectly!! Thanks.